# Raise ServiceWorker Push Notification Event

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, service-worker, web-worker

I'm developing a webApp, and want to send notifications using a ServiceWorker.

I have my sw.js and my main.js. I'm able to register my Service Worker and I'm able to send notifications using a command like:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {      
    reg.showNotification('Title', {
        body: 'body'
    });
});
```

But this is not calling my push event defined in the 'sw.js'.

For reference here is my "sw.js":

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

  const title = 'title test from push';
  const options = {
    body: 'body test from push.',
    icon: 'images/icon.png'
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

const title = 'Push Codelab';
const options = {
  body: 'Yay it works.',
  icon: 'images/icon.png',
  badge: 'images/badge.png'
};
self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
```

As additional information, in Chrome if I go in the Developer tool => Application Tab => Service Workers, and click on "push" button, the correct push event is raised. But, again, I'm not able to trigger it from my main page.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to do something you're actually not supposed to do or you've confused some things about the SW / push notification logic. What do you _actually_ mean by saying you cannot trigger it from your main page? How do you try to trigger it from your main page? Why would you try to trigger it from your main page? Please share the triggering code too :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I was out of scope with this question. I definitely confused something :)
Many thanks for the answer, and sorry for the silly question

Comment: You need a server-side script that will send the notification to your end user.  The service worker should get the vapidPublicKey and save for future push notifications